# Link Kinds Google App Engine using Python

Tags: class, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am new to app engine and I am trying to get my head around linking two kinds together, even after reading the documentation I am still approaching it too much from a relationship database model I think.

If I have a UserInformation class

```
class UserInformation(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.UserProperty()
    firstname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    lastname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    telephone = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
```

and then I want to have a book class so that a user can have multiple books

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    author = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    booktitle = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

how do I link the two classes together with a parent / child relationship? Is it something like

```
b = Book(parent=UserInformation, key=’some key’, author=’some author’, booktitle=’a great book’)
```

If it is, how do I extract the key? I can get the ID by

```
Users = UserInformation(UserInformation.username==’some user’).get()
User_key = Users.key.id()
```

But I can’t seem to get the key?

Any help gratefully received

Comment: Use the ndb.KeyProperty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is an owned relation then your strategy is fine.  As for accessing the key, you already have it in your code.

You use

```
User_key = Users.key.id()
```

The key is `Users.key`

However think about how you might use books.  If multiple people have the same book, you may want to consider creating a single canonical Book entity for each Book.

Then in the User you can either

- have a repeated `KeyProperty` which is a list of all keys of the books owned by a Person. or
- If they can have 000's of books then you would go back to an owned entity (has the user as a parent). This entity has a KeyProperty pointing the canonical Book entity, and probably a copy of the title, so you don't have to fetch the book as well for summary listings.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the additional idea

Comment: I can bring back the key but I am struggling to link the kinds together: b = Book(parent=UserInformation, key=userkey, author=’some author’, booktitle=’a great book’). I get the error BadArgumentError: Model constructor given key= does not accept id=, app=, namespace=, or parent=?

Comment: Re-read the error.  It is telling you that if you use parent you can't use the key argument.  Which is correct because the key will embody the parent any way. You should be either supplying a string `id` or let the system generate the id for you.  The key is a composite of a possible ancestor(s), appid, namespace, kind and id or key_name. I suggest you re-read the docs on keys  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass